# Preventing tampering of form fields in ASP.NET MVC EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, entity-framework-4.1

The default strongly-typed Edit page in ASP.NET MVC 3 generally exposes all fields for the Entity. While this is often workable, some fields are a security risk. For example a simplified magazine subscription entity might look like:

```
public void Subscription() {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string State { get; set; }
  public string Zip { get; set; }
  public DateTime SubscribedThru { get; set; }
}
```

If I provide an Edit page to let users change their own address, for example, it's a security risk to include the `SubscribedThru` field because a knowledgeable and malicious user could give themselves a free 10-year subscription by faking the date (even if I use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscribedThru)`. So I am not including that field in any way on the Edit page html (via razor).

I thought the answer might be to prevent binding attempts on `SubscribedThru` on the Edit method in the controller using something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude="SubscribedThru")] Subscription subscription) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    db.Entry(subscription).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  }
  return View(subscription);
}
```

When I get to the `SaveChanges();` line, it throws the error `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.` I believe that the SubscribedThru date (properly?) doesn't exist, and the empty value is less than SQL Server can handle. What surprises me is that it's even trying to update that field when I have Binding excluded for it.

So far my best solution seems to be to create a custom ViewModel that omits the SubscribedThru date, but that seems a lot of duplication of fields, validation, etc.; if possible I'd like to just make the one field `SubscribedThru` safe from user editing.

I can't say I fully understand the `UpdateModel` and `TryUpdateModel` methods and wonder if that's a direction to head? I played with them and EF throws errors for having duplicate objects (same key) which is perplexing.

Also, I'm not clear if the subscription data is preserved from the initial load in `public ActionResult Edit(int id)` in the controller all the way to the final `[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Subscription subscription)...` method, or does the line `db.Entry(subscription).State = EntityState.Modified;` try and set all the data (I thought it was just setting a flag indicating "edited-so-EF-should-save-this").

I'm a long-time .NET developer, just jumping in to my first ASP.NET MVC project, so I'm probably overlooking something painfully obvious. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far my best solution seems to be to create a custom ViewModel that omits the SubscribedThru date, but that seems a lot of duplication of fields, validation, etc.;

That is exactly what you should do to keep things neat & tidy.  [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) eases the `ViewModel` variation headache.

Comment: Using a ViewModel and AutoMapper seem like a "heavier" solution than UpdateModel with a white list. What would be the benefits of ViewModel + AutoMapper over the UpdateModel solution?

Comment: You have greater control and a generalized solution that doesn't rely on EF.

Answer (score 1):

This page contains an example of updating a model using `TryUpdateModel` (Listing 4):
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs

You can whitelist only the fields that you allow to be edited, which removes the security risk.

Comment: Yeah, I believe so.  It'll still do the ModelBinding stuff within TryUpdateModel though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I edited original question to cover `UpdateModel` which works, but I find baffling. Sure I'm overlooking something simple.